# How to get PHP switch case conditional statements code work properly on wordpress function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to automatically display different content each day of the week, using PHP switch case conditional statements, Example: I want to automatically display a particular content on Monday, different content on Tuesday, different on Wednesday and the rest, So i'm using the below code to display it through wordpress function.php, the below code worked just as i wanted but the only one problem, is that when i use the shortcode on a WordPress page where pagebuilder is activated, the out put does not display on the actual page where i pasted the shortcode but in the header, So i'm trying to make it display normally like any other shortcode, Please any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

I have latest version of WordPress installed

```
function todays_content(){

$date = date('l');
switch ($date) {
  case 'Sunday': $content = do_shortcode('[sunday_content]'); break;
  case 'Monday': $content = do_shortcode('[monday_content]'); break;
  case 'Tuesday': $content = do_shortcode('[tuesday_content]'); break;
  case 'Wednesday': $content = do_shortcode('[wednesday_content]'); break;
  case 'Thursday': $content = do_shortcode('[thursday_content]'); break;
  case 'Friday': $content = do_shortcode('[friday_content]'); break;
  case 'Saturday': $content = do_shortcode('[saturday_content]'); break;
  }
  echo '<div class="daily_contant">'.$content.'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'show_today_content', 'todays_content' );
```

Comment: thats a lot of code for: `echo 'Today is  '.date('l');`

Comment: WordPress shortcodes have to **return** data, not **echo** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function todays_content(){

    $date = date('l');
    switch ($date) {
      case 'Sunday': $content = do_shortcode('[sunday_content]'); break;
      case 'Monday': $content = do_shortcode('[monday_content]'); break;
      case 'Tuesday': $content = do_shortcode('[tuesday_content]'); break;
      case 'Wednesday': $content = do_shortcode('[wednesday_content]'); break;
      case 'Thursday': $content = do_shortcode('[thursday_content]'); break;
      case 'Friday': $content = do_shortcode('[friday_content]'); break;
      case 'Saturday': $content = do_shortcode('[saturday_content]'); break;
      }
      return '<div class="daily_contant">'.$content.'</div>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'show_today_content', 'todays_content' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use a switch in this case :) . You should return and not echo it instead

```
function todays_content(){   
    $today = date('l');
    return "Today is {$today}";
}

add_shortcode( 'show-today-content', 'todays_content' );
```

Usage:

```
[show-today-content]
```

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel Fernandez , but that is not what i'm trying to achieve, I have updated the above code to make it more detailed on what i'm trying to achieve here. The code is working as it should but the only problem i have is, when i use the shortcode [show-today-content] where wordpress page builder is activated, it shows but it dose not display at the exact location that i paste the shortcode, rather it shows on the top of the page after the site header, i don't know why this is happening

Comment: @IgweChukwuma you accepted this answer, then completely changed the question ?!?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't know why I got -15points for this :(

Comment: That was a mistake accepting this answer as the right answer @tim, I've updated the above code to what worked for me, cabrerahector answer helped.